# Calculate hours worked based on 8 hours shift using C# in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, .net-core

I am working on a time management application as a part of my project.
I am calculating days, hours and minutes based on 8 hours work shift.  But when I try to calculate total days remaining and days worked, I get wrong results from my calculations.

Please check my code

```
var LeaveTotal = TotalWork(LeaveDays, leaveHours, LeaveMintues);

var t1 = (int)LeaveTotal[0];
var t2 = (int)LeaveTotal[1];
var t3 = (int)LeaveTotal[2];

TimeSpan date1 = new TimeSpan(t1, t2, t3,0);
TimeSpan date2 = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0,0);
TimeSpan minutes = (date2.Subtract(date1));
```

Now, if there was a 10 days of work and someone has done 8 days and 5 hours work, then I should get 1 day and 3 hours as a remainder (based on 8 hours work shift), but I am getting funny results.

```
public double[] TotalWork(double days, double totalhours, double minutes)
{
    double[] total = new double[3];

    var hours = Math.Floor(minutes / 60);
    totalhours += hours;

    days += Math.Floor(totalhours / 8);
    totalhours = totalhours % 8;

    var remainingMins = minutes - (hours * 60);

    total[0] = (days);
    total[1] = (totalhours);
    total[2] = (remainingMins);

    return total;
}
```

Please help, I am badly stuck here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in that you are using TimeSpan subtraction, you should use your own subtraction method between the two dates, since you are considering 8 hours in a day, you can use a function like this that accepts two arrays of double that each contain days, hours and the minutes.

```
static double[] SubtractDates(double[] initialTime, double[] subtractedTime)
{
double initialDays = initialTime[0] + initialTime[1] / 8 + initialTime[2] / (8 * 60);
double subtractedDays = subtractedTime[0] + subtractedTime[1] / 8 + subtractedTime[2] / (8 * 60);

double remainingDays = initialDays - subtractedDays;

double remainingHours = Math.Floor((remainingDays % 1) * 8);
double remainingMinutes = Math.Floor(((remainingDays % 1) * 8 % 1) * 60);

remainingDays = Math.Floor(remainingDays);

double[] result = { remainingDays, remainingHours, remainingMinutes };
return result;
}
```

Of course the two time arrays will have to have first went through your TotalWork() function to be compatible with the 8 hour day.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro,  I have just tried that, if I input 8 days and 5 hours worked out of 10 days.  then the answer should be 1 day and 3 hours.   for example   double[] totaldays = new double[3];
            totaldays[0] = 10;
            totaldays[1] = 0;
            totaldays[2] = 0;

            var total = SubtractDates(LeaveTotal, totaldays);   leave total is 8 days, 5 hours and 0 mins

Comment: I guess if we keep remainingDays = Math.Floor(remainingDays); to int than it might solve the issue.